# Google Map Circle for single address not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get a single circle for my google map, i am not using the multiple array as it is specified in the google map document because i just want one single point with the circle to be shown in the map.
I don't know where exactly am i making error, please will someone let me know where exactly am i making error.

this is my code

```js
 var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(25.800693, 55.976199);
        var marker;
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: loc
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: loc
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
        }
        function toggleBounce() {

            if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }
        cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.800693, 55.976199),
            radius: 50
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: move the code that creates the circle to the end of `initialize`

Answer (score 0):

Move the initialization of the circle inside the initialize function, so it is initialized after the map, not before.

```js
var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(25.800693, 55.976199);
var marker;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: loc
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: loc
  });
  cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.800693, 55.976199),
    radius: 50
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {

  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```